# Android SeekBar mark where are the values

Tags: android, seekbar

I have SeekBar with 3 value (left, on center and right) and I will like to put some mark where progess level are, e.g. on center to put vertical line over bar or something like that.

Is this possible or it's might be better to use some different component?

Like on this image, I need something like this red line

[image]

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what you want to do. Can you be more clear or illustrate this with a Screenshot?

Comment: So, is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: If this is for choosing one of the above listed states, why does a `Spinner` not work for you?

Comment: I try Spinner and I think it's better solution to use this layout. In fact I really want to create LUDO game and try to use 4 SeekBars where user can select state for players (player, AI, off) but I think it would be nicer to have marked where are the states on SeekBar. Or perhaps is there any other component to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d).
Save an image of what you want the labels to be in a png image then add it to your resources in your project.

Here is some code I used, where my image was the android launcher icon:

```
seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable d = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
seekbar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone reaches this question now: In the meanwhile there is a discrete SeekBar, that does exactly, what was questioned: It displays the discrete points, that can be chosen as marks.